# Generating a caption for the figure automatically

Tags: captions, datatool

I have hundreds of pictures included in latex file.
Is there any way, how to create a caption for each automatically?
e.g. file picture1 would have generated a caption picture1.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
        \section{Title}
    \subsection{SubTitle}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth]{Figure1.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth]{Figure2.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth]Figure3.png}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth]{Figure4.png}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/3a7teq/is_there_a_way_to_automatically_add_the_file_name/

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It would help if you edit your question and supply a small example of how you place the images in your document.  For example, do you simply use `\includegraphics` to place them in the raw, or do you wrap each one in a `figure` environment?  Do you include these images manually, or do you have some sort of automation loop to place the images?

Comment: I added the code snippet to the original post.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining a new environment it is possible to capture the name of the figure file and insert it in the caption.
[image: z]

`ShowSubFigure` has two paramemeters, the file names of two figures to show side by side as subfigures.

`ShowFigure` also as two parameters: the filename of a single figure that will be centered on the page and its width.

**UPDATED** after follow-up

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep = space, labelfont=bf}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{}% without the word "Figure"
    
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text    (to be removed)
\usepackage{showframe} % show margins (to be removed)

\newenvironment{ShowSubFigure}[2]   
{   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{#1}
    \caption{\texttt{#1}}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{#2}
    \caption{\texttt{#2}}
\end{minipage}
}   

\newenvironment{ShowFigure}[2]
{\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=#2, keepaspectratio]{#1}
        \caption{\texttt{#1}}
    \end{figure}        
}   
    
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt} % figure on top of the page
\setlength{\@fpsep}{15pt} % float separation
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\kant[1]
    
    \begin{figure*}[th!]
        \begin{ShowSubFigure}{example-image-a}{example-image-c}\end{ShowSubFigure}  
    \end{figure*}
    
    \begin{figure*}[ht!]
        \begin{ShowSubFigure}{example-image-b}{example-image-b}\end{ShowSubFigure}
    \end{figure*}

    \kant[2]
    
    \begin{figure*}[th!]
        \begin{ShowSubFigure}{example-image-c}{example-image-a}\end{ShowSubFigure}
    \end{figure*}

    \kant[9]

    \begin{ShowFigure}{example-grid-100x100pt}{0.3\textwidth}\end{ShowFigure}

\end{document}
```

**AUTOMATED ALTERNATIVE**

If a list of figures is generated from the OS (like `dir / b / s * .jpg > ListFig.txt`), the process can be automated to produce a document with all the thumbnails.

A `.csv` (comma separated values) file is then constructed with two filenames, comma separated, per line.

The data is loaded into a database (using the package`datatool`) which is then traversed row by row, while inserting the file names into the `ShowSubFigure` environment.
[image: x]

This very basic example produces 7 pages of 6 images per page, numbered sequentially.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\usepackage{datatool} % added <<<<<<<<<<    
\usepackage{calculator}% added <<

\newcounter{nrow}
\setcounter{nrow}{1}

 \begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{ImagesList.csv}   
        example-image-a, example-image-c
        example-image-b, example-image-b
        example-image-c, example-image-a
        example-image-a, example-image-c
        example-image-b, example-image-b
        example-image-c, example-image-a
        example-image-a, example-image-c
        example-image-b, example-image-b
        example-image-c, example-image-a
        example-image-a, example-image-c
        example-image-b, example-image-b
        example-image-c, example-image-a
        example-image-a, example-image-c
        example-image-b, example-image-b
        example-image-c, example-image-a
        example-image-a, example-image-c
        example-image-b, example-image-b
        example-image-c, example-image-a
        example-image-a, example-image-c
        example-image-b, example-image-b
        example-image-c, example-image-a
\end{filecontents*}

\newenvironment{ShowSubFigure}[2]
{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{#1}
    \subcaption{\texttt{#1}}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \addtocounter{figure}{1}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{#2}
    \subcaption{\texttt{#2}}
\end{minipage}
}   

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\@arabic\c@figure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
 \DTLloaddb[noheader]{index}{ImagesList.csv} % load the database
    
\DTLforeach{index}{\first=Column1, \second=Column2}{%
        \INTEGERDIVISION{\value{nrow}}{3}{\sola}{\solb}
        \ifthenelse{\solb =1}{\clearpage}{}%
        \begin{figure*}% display two figure side by side
            \begin{ShowSubFigure}{\first}{\second}\end{ShowSubFigure}                           
        \end{figure*}\stepcounter{nrow}
    }   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the first solution. However, the figures are now overflowing from the single page. Is there any way how to make them distributed to following pages?

Comment: @Luctex  Each time you invoke `\begin{ShowSubFigure}` inside the environment `figure* ` it will put 2 figures side by side. If there is not enough space on a page for more of two,  then  you should start another `figure*`. Perhaps you can expand  your question with a more realistic example, including some text.

Comment: @Luctex   The `figure*` is a float, so it should go to the next page as a whole (4 images). Try my  example with the example images,  adding some text before. Next try it with your images.